# Including other fields of data when using outsurv option in proc lifetest

Tags: sas, survival-analysis

Consider the following code. it generates a new data set of `OUTPUT` when it is executed. By default, `OUTPUT` has five fields of: `Time` , `Censoring`, survival estimation and its two confidence limits.

How can I get the `outsurv` option to keep other existing fields in `DATA`?

```
proc lifetest data=DATA outsurv=OUTPUT notable;     
    time Time*Censoring(1);
run;
```

**A SAMPLE DATA**

I want the `Name` column to be included in `OUTPUT`.

```
data DATA;
   input Name $ 1-25 Time Censoring;
   datalines;
Vincent, Martina          34 0
Phillipon, Marie-Odile    28 0
Gunter, Thomas            27 0
Harbinger, Nicholas       36 0
Benito, Gisela            32 1
Rudelich, Herbert         39 0
Sirignano, Emily          12 0
Morrison, Michael         32 0
;
run;
```

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense since its the survival table and can have multiple observations reflected at a single point in time, the number of events.

Comment: This is not the case in my dataset. But I see your point. Perhaps that is why I cannot find a straightaway command for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to add the feature. You'll need to merge the output back to your input data. Keep in mind if there are ties, in terms of event time/censoring you'll have multiple matches in your data. Make sure the output is what you expect.